# Shared library mysteriously doesn't get linked to application

Tags: linux, g++, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking

I have a shared library (libhoard.so) that I'm trying to link with a simple test binary. However, depending on the machine I compile on the shared library doesn't show up in the test binary.  I'm not sure what differences exist on the machines and is partly why I'm asking the question.  *I'm curious what I can do to troubleshoot why the shared library doesn't show up on the test binary on the "broken" machine?*

---

I used this command to compile both binaries (libhoard.so is in the same directory):

```
$ g++ -L. -lhoard hoard_test.o
```

Broken machine:

```
$ ldd a.out 
  linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0x00858000)
  libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x004dc000)
  libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00aaf000)
  libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00675000)
  /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x00d18000)
  libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x0040d000)
```

Working machine:

```
$ ldd a.out 
  linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0x00110000)
  libhoard.so (0x00111000) <----------------- THERE IT IS!
  libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x03ba8000)
  libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0x007a9000)
  libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00bf7000)
  libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x0063e000)
  libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0x007d4000)
  libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x007db000)
  /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x0061e000)
```

---

Here is some random version information:

Broken machine:

```
$ uname -srv
Linux 2.6.38-11-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 12 21:18:14 UTC 2011
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3) 4.6.1
```

Working machine:

```
$ uname -srv
Linux 2.6.25.3-18.fc9.i686 #1 SMP Tue May 13 05:38:53 EDT 2008
$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.3.0 20080428 (Red Hat 4.3.0-8)
```

Comment: Is the working machine a 64-bit install while the broken is a 32-bit install?

Comment: Both are 32-bit (output of `uname -m` is i686)

Comment: Are there #def's related to test and production. The linker wont include a link to a library that is not used.

Comment: If there is no error on linking on the "broken" machine, do you get any error while trying to run the program on it?

Comment: Is it linking a static version on the "broken" machine? do you get any unresolved symbol link errors? Presumably not. What happens when the program runs?

Comment: There aren't any errors on linking or running the application.  The library replaces memory allocation code (malloc/free), and I call both within the test application.  I can tell when the shared library is used because I added a print statement to fire when calls are intercepted.

Comment: So, to answer blueshift's question, when the program runs I see the program's output, but not the shared library's output.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**tl;dr version: Add `-Wl,--no-as-needed` to the link command.**

After a series of experimentation and conversations with the OP, I've figured out what's going on.

In the latest version of Ubuntu, `ld` uses `--as-needed` by default. What that does is to remove references to libraries that are not explicitly required.

The way Hoard works is as an `LD_PRELOAD` library. i.e., you are not supposed to need to use functions in `libhoard.so` directly. Of course, you *could* link in `libhoard` directly if you wanted to...unless `--as-needed` is used, of course.

After discovering this, the solution is simple. Just add `-Wl,--no-as-needed` to the `gcc` linking command.