# linking an executable against a shared library

Tags: c++, linker, g++

I have a basic question from which I could not find the solution around.
Say that I build a shared library `toto` made of the following header and source files:

toto.h

```
void print();
```

toto.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "toto.h"
void print()
{
std::cout<<"WHAT A GREAT LIBRARY"<<std::endl;
}
```

Based on these file I create my shared library using

`g++ -fPIC -shared -I. -c toto.cpp -o libtoto.so`

Next, I want to use my freshly created shared library in a test file:

test.cpp

```
#include "toto.h"

int main()
{
    print();
}
```

to do so, I link my executable against the shared library using

`g++ -I. -L. -ltoto test.cpp`

and I get my `a.out` executable file.

When I do a `ldd a.out` I get the following output:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff322f5000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fb7e7c24000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fb7e7865000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fb7e7568000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fb7e7f4d000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fb7e7352000)
```

where I do not see any dependency of my executable on `toto` shared library. Everything seems like during the link process my library has been statically bound to my executable. This seems confirmed by the fact that I can call `a.out` from everywhere without setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to the path where my `libtoto.so` is stored. Is that actually the case ? If so, what did I missed or misunderstand in the aforementioned commands to reach that point?

FYI, this example was run on ubuntu 12.04, g++ 4.6.3

EDIT:

I could find in the meantime that this code produces a "correct" 
executable in the sense that the `ldd` displays a dependency on `libtoto` shared library and that the executable could not be started without setting the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable:

```
g++ -I ./mydylib/ -fpic -c mydylib/toto.cpp -o mydylib/toto.o
g++ -shared -o mydylib/libtoto.so mydylib/toto.o
g++ -I ./mydylib/ -L ./mydylib/ test.cpp -ltoto -o ldd_correct
```

while this one still produces a "wrong" executable with the aforementionned features:

```
g++ -I ./mydylib -fpic -shared -c mydylib/toto.cpp -o mydylib/libtoto.so
g++ -I ./mydylib -L ./mydylib test.cpp -ltoto -o ldd_wrong
```

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814707). Does the provided answer solve your issue?

Comment: Order of arguments to `g++` matters a lot. The `-ltoto` should be placed after source (e.g. `toto.cpp`) and object files.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Shared library mysteriously doesn't get linked to application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814707/shared-library-mysteriously-doesnt-get-linked-to-application)

Comment: Thanks guys for your help but unfortunately none of your suggestions solve the problem. It is very weird.

Comment: So, does `./a.out` print the message?  If you delete the `.so` and re-run, what happens?  (FWIW, on the Redhat Enterprise Linux Server 5.8 ldd shows the expected dependency, suggesting it might be another change to `ld` behaviour, possibly made when the changes Michael links to were made).

Comment: `./a.out` actually prints the message with or without `libtoto.so`. It really seems that my library has been statically bound to the executable. I ran my example on ubuntu 12.04. Perhaps is there some "slight" changes in `ld` behaviour depending on the distro ? I will look deeper in `ld` documentation.

Comment: What version of g++ and what and what OS are you on?

Comment: ubuntu 12.04, g++ 4.6.3

Answer (score 1):

My guess is because it is such a simple library, it was optimised out. Does it still happen with more complex libraries? Have you tried passing a `-O0` flag?

I've tried but I can't reproduce the results - my `ldd` shows

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffb79fe000)
libtoto.so (0x00007f8a78316000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f8a77f2e000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f8a77c2a000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f8a7851a000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f8a77924000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f8a7770d000)
```

On Ubuntu 14.04 gcc version 4.8.2

However, as I expected, `g++ -I. -L. -ltoto test.cpp` did not work - I had to run `g++ -I. -L. test.cpp -ltoto` instead.

Comment: I tried to link against `boost-date-time` and indeed I get the `libboost_date_time.so.1.55.0` that appears in my `ldd` call. However, compiling with `-O0` flags does not help for my personal library.

Comment: Interesting. Try to make your own library more complex (copy paste some complex code from elsewhere into it) and see if it is still not in the `ldd` output. If it isn't, it means maybe it's due to the way you are linking libraries. If it is there, then you're current simple library is just so simple it really is being optimised out.

Answer (score 0):

I could finally find the reason for my problem:

When compiling and linking my shared library in a single GCC step, I was adding a wrong `-c` flag for my toto.cpp source file. This seems to break the build for the executable as you can see by comparing the three following building modes:

Two GCC steps building for the shared library

```
g++ -I. -fpic -c toto.cpp -o toto.o
g++ -shared -o libtoto.so toto.o
g++ -I. -L. test.cpp -ltoto -o ldd_correct
```

Single GCC step for building the shared library

```
g++ -I. -fpic -shared -o libtoto.so toto.cpp
g++ -I. -L. test.cpp -ltoto -o ldd_also_correct
```

Single GCC step for building the shared library --> the -c breaks something

```
g++ -I. -fpic -shared -o libtoto.so -c toto.cpp
g++ -I. -L. test.cpp -ltoto -o ldd_wrong
```

Comment: My take on it: `-c` tells the compiler to generate a `.o` object file, and the -o `libtoto.so` gives it a filename which is misleading as it's not in ".so" shared library format internally.  It seems the `-shared` flag is ignored when `-c` is also specified.  So, your `-ltoto` ends up finding the `libtoto.so` file, but then links it in statically as that's what the file content supports.  Pity it didn't print an error message and exit....